# Vue 3 and Window object reactivity

Tags: vue.js, window, reactive, vue-reactivity, composable

I'm facing an issue I'm not able to solve, so I need some help!

**Problem**

I would like to listen up changes on `location.href` value.

How could I detect changes in `window.location` object?

I need to create a composable that updates some values depending on href changes of my SPA.

I got something like this:

```js
export default function useNavigationList () {
  const currentLocation = ref(window.location) // try 1
  const currentHref = ref(window.location.href) // try 2
  const toRefLocation = toRef(window, 'location') // try 3
  const toRefhRef= toRef(window.location, 'href') // try 4

  watch(currentLocation, () => console.log(currentLocation.value)) // Not working

  watch(currentHref, () => console.log(currentHref.value)) // Not working

  watch(toRefLocation , () => console.log(currentLocation.value), { deep: true }) // Not working

  watch(toRefhRef, () => console.log(toRefhRef.value)) // Not working
}
```

No one is working :(

How could I get a reactive `window` object? Or at least, a reactive `href`??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue's reactivity system won't pick up changes to window.location or window.location.href as you've tried to do.

You could use Vue Router, you can watch the `$route` object for changes:

```
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

export default function useNavigationList() {
  const currentLocation = ref(window.location) // try 1
  const currentHref = ref(window.location.href) // try 2
  const toRefLocation = ref(window, 'location') // try 3
  const toRefhRef = ref(window.location, 'href') // try 4

  const route = useRoute()

  watch(
    () => route.fullPath,
    (newPath, oldPath) => {
      console.log('Route changed:', newPath)

      currentLocation.value = window.location
      currentHref.value = window.location.href
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Hmm yeah! With vue-router its easy, however I'm using InertiaJS, there is no vue-router. But you point me in the right direction. I just have to listen up routes changes (InertiaJS router events) in order to react to location changes. Thanks!